# CSS selector for certain position of matched classes

Tags: css, class, css-selectors

I have the following divs:

```
<div class="c">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>//this
</div>
<div class="c">
  <div class="a"></div>//this
  <div class="a"></div>//this
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
<div class="c">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a CSS selector that lets me select .a elements situated in 3rd,4th and 5th position of the .a matched results?

Something similar to [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) in jQuery.

:nth-child() is not of help here as this is just a simplified case.

[This is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0x6Lzbh/) with the results using jQuery. I want to know if there is a solution using just CSS.

Comment: maybe so ? - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/kdym6f5a/

Comment: What I am looking for is exactly the eq() but in CSS,if it exists, just give the number of the position from the matched results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent to jQuery's `:eq()` in CSS. In plain English, there is no selector for the nth element matching a complex selector (in your example, the 3rd, 4th and 5th elements matching the selector `.a`).

Just for the sake of completeness (because someone is going to say ["well, actually..."](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html)), the specific elements are, of course, reachable with

```
.c:nth-child(1) > .a:nth-child(3), .c:nth-child(2) > .a:nth-child(1), .c:nth-child(2) > .a:nth-child(2)
```

But that assumes that is *exactly* how your markup appears, which is seldom ever a realistic assumption to make, especially if the page is dynamically generated.

In the very unlikely event that your markup is static and you can *rely on* the 3rd, 4th and 5th `.a` elements being in those exact positions, by all means use the selector above. But if their positions or structure can vary, then you will need other ways to identify them in CSS, for example with an additional class name.

Comment: I was looking for the eq() but in CSS, or some other clever way. The other result is not what I was looking for. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: markup will be dynamic. The exact scenario is I want to apply a style to the next and previous .a of a clicked .a. Several clicks will be made so I need to rely in some solution as eq() but I wondered if there was something to be done just adding a class to the clicked (and css doing the rest).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.c:nth-child(1) .a:nth-child(3) { background:yellow; }
.c:nth-child(2) .a:nth-child(2), .c:nth-child(2) .a:nth-child(1) { background:yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="a">c1-a1</div>
  <div class="a">c1-a2</div>
  <div class="a">c1-a3 //this</div>
</div>
<div class="c">
  <div class="a">c2-a1 //this</div>
  <div class="a">c2-a2 //this</div>
  <div class="a">c2-a3</div>
</div>
<div class="c">
  <div class="a">c3-a1</div>
  <div class="a">c3-a2</div>
  <div class="a">c3-a3</div>
</div>
```